# setVisible() method not working for JButton placed on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

In my Swing application I have MainFrame with "Add Customer" Button. When I click on the "Add Customer" Button I want Customer form to appear while MainFrame disappearing. Customer form has only JTabbedPane. AddCustomerPanel is a separate class which has only cancel button. AddCustomerPanel has added to Customer form's JTabbedPane as a tab. When I click on cancel button I want Customer frame disappear and mainframe appear again.I tried using setVisible() method. But it didn't work. Please help me to do this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private JButton btnMain;

    MainFrame(){
        setSize(400,200);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());        
        btnMain = new JButton("Add Customer");

        btnMain.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        new Customer().setVisible(true);
                        this.setVisible(false); // Not working
                }
        });

        add(btnMain);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Customer extends JFrame{
    private JTabbedPane tabMain;

    Customer(){
        setSize(500,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tabMain = new JTabbedPane();
        tabMain.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(490,290));
        tabMain.add("Add Customer",new AddCustomerPanel());
        add(tabMain);   
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class AddCustomerPanel extends JPanel{

    private JButton btnCancel;

    AddCustomerPanel(){
        setSize(400,200);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        this.setVisible(false); // Not working
                        new MainFrame().setVisible(true);

                }
        });
        add(btnCancel); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the Answer :)

SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).setVisible(false);
new MainFrame().setVisible(true);

Comment: @Dukeling - I already posted it as an answer. But I have to wait 20hrs to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).setVisible(false);

new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
```